# Discord PIP Install Error

Tags: python, pip, discord

I tried to install discord libraries in PIP but received an error, this is the error is received in screenshot form:

https://gyazo.com/7fb01731b10773ecfba0ae541a4a69ca

I do not know why this has happened, could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Could you paste the error in the question?

Comment: All of it is in the screenshot?

Comment: Try `pip install websockets` and then install discord

Comment: Same error, there is one error - file cannot be found :/ near the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade pip to the latest version.