# ''Module "Discord" not found'' in Python3.x during PIP installation

Tags: python, pip, bots, python-asyncio, discord.py

I have a small question, my Discord bot is written in Python and I keep getting errors. This is the code of my bot:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Calculating messages...')

client.run('You arent gonna get my token =D')
```

And when I run it this error comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Testing\discordbt.py", line 1, in <module>
import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

I really don't know what to do, all I did is the following commands in CMD:

```
pip install discord.py
pip install asyncio
```

That's all, I made sure the modules installed without errors, and they did, everything is up and such, and I know you need some other "programs" and I have installed the following programs: `Python 3.6.3 64x` and `Python 3.7.0a2 64x`

My PC is from a 64x bit architecture so it completely matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord PIP Install Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133128/discord-pip-install-error)

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right interpreter for your script? Pretty common to see "ModuleNotFound" when you have several Python dists installed.

Comment: Interpeter? Dist? Explain to me :) @lotrus28

Comment: @DeadlyFirex Interpreter is an the program that runs your scripts. Dist is a distribution -- an interpreter paired with packages. Each distribution has its own installation folder and you can have multiple dists on one computer. For example, you can have Python2, Python3 and Anaconda installed at the same time.
Each of these has its own package addition procedure. E.g. `pip` will only add a package to P2, `pip3` -- to P3. If you used `pip` to install the package but use the P3 interpreter in ur project, you should either switch to P2 or use `pip3` to add the package to P3 folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that pip is installing the module in a foreign directory to the python version you run your script with. Try specifying the python version by appending the version number to the terminal command as such `python3.6 -m pip install discord.py`. If that doesn't work try using `pip3` instead of `pip`.

edit: Also do not try to install `asyncio`, it's part of the standard library.